# How can I move object y direction and make "gravitation"

Tags: java

I'm trying to start my programming, with a program in java.grativation means that we have a drag&drop function with laptops, cars, etc, and another with balloons. If the user is "dropping" 2 balloons on laptop, it would fly. 3 balloons to cars etc. Can u give me some advice how should i start? Everything moves on Y axis.

Comment: my humble request (advice) would be to start writing some code and see what happens - Give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about collisions, every object should have (at least) 5 vars:
x position
y position
y velocity
balloon count
weight (relative to balloons)

From there, you can use balloon count to calculate acceleration needed for y-velocity ***acceleration const* * (weight - balloon count)**, and in turn y-position. x-position will remain constant, and is used for displaying.